# Is it possible to have mamba aggregate a list of yaml files during the create command?

Tags: mamba

I have a process where envs are created and then multiple env files are used to update the env via `mamba env update` .

The problem is that I'm running commands in parallel and the lockfile doesn't appear to work with `mamba env update`  only for `mamba env create` . https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba/issues/1582

Without me having to merge all the env files myself is there a way to do something like this:
`mamba create --yes --quiet --name=myenv python=3.6 --file=deps1.yml --file=deps2.yml --file=deps2.yml`